# What does "void *(*)(void *)" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, pthreads, function-pointers, void-pointers

It's the parameter in `pthread_create()`. I think each part means:

- `void *`: The return value is a void pointer.
- `(*)`: It's a pointer to a function.
- `(void *)`: It takes an untyped pointer as a parameter.

Is that correct?

Comment: Just check it yourself on cdecl.org.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes**, it is the signature of a nameless function pointer that takes and returns `void *`.

If it had a name (as in a variable) it would be:

```
void *(*myFuncName)(void*)
```

Comment: For which compilers is this syntax legal? The R package igraph does not compile on the CRAN Solaris server due to a "syntax error" around the use of "void (*)(void)": https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-patched-solaris-x86/igraph-00install.html