# What is void(*)(void *)

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “void *(*)(void *)” mean in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371171/what-does-void-void-mean-in-c)

What does the type void(*)(void *)  mean?

I came across this type in the example code for the book "Mastering Algorithms with C"

```
void list_init(List *list, void (*destroy)(void *data)) 
{
...

...
}
```

Comment: a function pointer to a function that takes a void pointer as parameter

Comment: Spiral rule: *pointer to a function taking a pointer to void and returning nothing*.

Comment: By the way, if you're using C++11, this becomes `std::function<void(void *)>`, which is much more readable and useful. While doing that, you could replace the `void *` with a template if you're after any type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a function pointer.

```
void (*destroy)(void *data)
```

`destroy` is a pointer to a function which returns `void` and takes a `void*` as an argument.

[cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) is a useful tool for discerning complex C declarations.  Also, take a look at [the spiral rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707096/spiral-rule-and-declaration-follows-usage-for-parsing-c-expressions).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. 
I just figured that the author was using this function pointer to assign the function 'free(void *)' (stdlib.h) to the function pointer 'destroy'. 
Not the most readable way to do it tough. Does anyone know of a good reason this might be useful, in spite of readability issues?

I'm not sure if my comment here is clear enough. I don't know if I could post the entire code here (copyrights).

Comment: @user1535080 `destroy` is a parameter, and `free` isn't the only possible argument. " Not the most readable way to do it tough" -- what would you do instead? "Does anyone know of a good reason this might be useful" -- yes; to pass an arbitrary "destroy" function to `list_init`.

Comment: @user1535080: Consider a type which allows for customized deallocation routines.  The function prototype is one that returns `void` and takes a `void*` as a parameter, but perhaps you want to do the deallocation yourself (a self-managed heap) or just perform some logging.  This lets you assign any function with a specific signature to handle the deallocation.  I realize that the function pointer syntax seems strange at first, but this is C, and after you get some experience you won't think it is unreadable (plus, as Jim said, how else would you do it?)

Comment: For which compilers is this syntax legal? The R package igraph does not compile on the CRAN Solaris server due to a "syntax error" around the use of "void (*)(void)": https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-patched-solaris-x86/igraph-00install.html

Comment: could you also write it without the parenthesis as `void* destroy(void *data)` ?

Comment: or I guess that would make it a function that returns a void pointer and not a pointer to a void function?

Comment: @JorgeLuque: Yes, that would be incorrect

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, its a pointer to which any function can be cast to void(*)(void *) and the function parameter void * can be any type.