# I can't understand this variable type in c++ vector declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, variables, vector, types

In the C++ code, there is a declaration like

```
vector<void *( *)(void *)> t_list;
```

I have never seen `void*(*)(void *)` variable type before. Can somebody explain what that type means?

Comment: This should help: [The Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "void \*(\*)(void \*)" mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371171/what-does-void-void-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This vector is declared to hold function pointers, that is, pointers to functions. As declared, it allows you to add pointers to functions that look like this:

```
void* someFunc(void* someArg);
```

Then you can use the function pointers stored in the vector to... call them, as

Here is a simple example. I don't do anything with the `void* arg` but in real code, I would assume it will be used for something:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void* printHello(void* arg)
{
    std::cout << "Hello";
    return arg;
}

void* printSpace(void* arg)
{
    std::cout << " ";
    return arg;
}

void* printWorld(void* arg)
{
    std::cout << "World";
    return arg;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<void *( *)(void *)> t_list;
    t_list.push_back(printHello);
    t_list.push_back(printSpace);
    t_list.push_back(printWorld);
    
    // This prints out "Hello World"
    for(const auto& f : t_list)
    {
        f(nullptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just wonder why we declare like void * (* )(void * ) for "void* somefunc(void *somearg)". In my knowledge, type should be declared like vector<void * (void *)>.(I just removed '( * )')

Comment: Well, I can't tell you exactly what the reason is, but that `(*)` basically tells the compiler that this is a function pointer, as this is where a function's name usually goes. If you wanted to make a `typedef` for this function pointer, this is where the name of the typedef would go, like this: `typedef void* (*myFuncPtrType)(void*);`